# Before-Action method in symfony2

Tags: session, symfony, remember-me

I want to write a common code in my symfony2 application that should be executed before calling any action-method. How Can I do it?

At the time of login-success, I am storing some data in session. If the user visit the application later with remember-me functionality. I want to restore the session data. The common code is to restore the session data.

Comment: Why do you keep the session data stored after the session expired or after the user logged out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method to setup before and after Filters are available in the documentation. Please 
see  the link http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

Comment: I have created a Symfony bundle based of the Symfony cookbook mentioned. https://github.com/expertcoder/before-after-bundle  . hopefully this can be useful to someone else. I invite constructive feedback about the bundle. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JMSAopBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSAopBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst), intercepting all action method for a given controller (or any controller).

Answer (score 1):

I think that https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1975 can be helpful. Basically you have to create listener which will be listen at `kernel.controller` event and call some method from controller there.