# Symfony some logic before controller

Tags: symfony, before-filter

I'm a newbie to Symfony and I'm trying to switch my current project over to it.

For most of my controllers I need to do some multiple checks BEFORE executing the controller. Then if certain conditions are met for the check, forward them and show a different view, otherwise continue on to what they requested.

For example I have a group of controllers which should only be executed if the user is in a crew otherwise it loads a view saying "you're not in a crew".

This is very straight forward in procedural code, yet in OOP seems to get more complex, and now within a framework I seem to find myself even more limited.

**How does one add logic before the controller is executed?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429788/before-action-method-in-symfony2

Comment: Consider just adding the checks to your controller to get started.  Once you get a bit more comfortable with S2 then get in to the filter stuff as suggested by TheSmose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set up before-filter logic.  It's not something simple enough to write into a post here, but here's a good tutorial on doing so.  If you have a specific issue with it, post here and I'll try to update with help: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use the before filter, and when it comes to "throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('This action needs a valid token!'); " i get a 500 error with symfony_error_log "uncaught exception" instead of 403, i also tried the "throw new AccessDeniedException('This action needs a valid token!'); ", same thing happens, do you know what might be the reason? thanks

Comment: I have created a bundle based of the Symfony cookbook, to save you from needed to code it yourself.

https://github.com/expertcoder/before-after-bundle

I invite contructive feedback about the bundle. thanks.